# Variable scope in model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had just debug a validation function for my model and faced with behavior I can't understand
So, model has a field `address` that I validate using custom functions.
First, I wrote such code

```
    puts address
    if address[0..3] != 'rtmp'
      address = "rtmp://#{address}"
    end
    puts address
```

And the output was:

```
"abc"
""
```

I mean that the second `puts` output empty string.

Then I replaced code with this (added `self.` each time I call `address`)
puts address

```
puts self.address    
if self.address[0..3] != 'rtmp'
  self.address = "rtmp://#{self.address}"
end
puts self.address
```

And that worked exactly as I expect, outputting

```
"abc"
"rtmp://abc"
```

What's the problem? I thought in that case `address` and `self.address` are the same. But it occurs not being so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is because in a Model when a ***set*** an Attribute, like `address = "rtmp://#{address}"` you are creating a local variable 
(inside of the scope of the method) and that will disapear when the method ends. This will not happend with a ***get*** an Attribute because the program
will not find the variable in a the most local scope and then will look in the scope of the Model and there will find your Attribute `address`.

So, for educational porpuses, you should try something like this:

```
puts address
if address[0..3] != 'rtmp'
  address = "rtmp://#{address}"
  puts address                      #to print the local variable
end
puts address                #to print the Attribute
```

And check for yourself this behavior.

But your method should be:

```
puts address
if address[0..3] != 'rtmp'              #without self because is get
  self.address = "rtmp://#{address}"    #with self because is set
end
puts address
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've expected. But I still don't understand why does it creates a local variable. It will do so every time I try to assign a value to attribute using `=` and not calling it with `self.`? It just always interprets such expression in that way?

Comment: This is just how Ruby work, local scope takes precedence.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you!

Comment: It could be a bit strange, but with time you'll get use to.